# how to render data from server code to ejs template?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, sequelize.js, ejs

I'm a newbie of node js and ejs. Now I'm going to pass data from server code to ejs template.
I made db on mysql and then get data by controller using sequelize.

```js
// faq.ejs
 <li>
    <div class="title">js data</div>
        <ul>
           <% if (data) { %>
               <li><%= data[0].title %></li>  
           <% } %>

        </ul>
 </li>
```

```js
// routes/index.js
const category = require('../controllers/controller');

router.get('/ko/faq', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('ko/faq', { 
        data: category.getAll() // 
    });
});
```

```js
// controller.js
exports.getAll = (req, res) => {
    Category.findAll()
    .then( async (data) => {
      var parentArr = [];
      var childArr = [];
      for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i].parent_id === null) {
          data[i]['dataValues']["children"] = [];
           parentArr.push(data[i]['dataValues']);
          //console.log(parentArr)
        } else {
           childArr.push(data[i]['dataValues']);
           // console.log(childArr)
        }}
      for(let i = 0; i < parentArr.length; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < childArr.length; j++) {
          if(parentArr[i].id === childArr[j].parent_id) {
           await parentArr[i].children.push(childArr[j]);  
          }
        }    
      }
        console.log(parentArr)
        res.render('ko/faq', { data: parentArr });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send("Error -> " + err)
      })
    };
```

To make a data into tree structure, I made that code(it's not important).

If I put a string on data in index.js, it is rendered well on screen.
But the problem is `parentArr` defined in controller is not came.

When I routed to /ko/faq page on localhost, an error is showed up.

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
    at /Users/daye.k/repo/dream-home/controllers/ko_cat.controller.js:60:13
    at tryCatcher (/Users/daye.k/repo/dream-home/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/daye.k/repo/dream-home/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/daye.k/repo/dream-home/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/daye.k/repo/dream-home/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/daye.k/repo/dream-home/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:725:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/Users/daye.k/repo/dream-home/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue (/Users/daye.k/repo/dream-home/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/daye.k/repo/dream-home/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/daye.k/repo/dream-home/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
```

I think the problem is from 'asynchronous', so I put await/async.
but it also doesn't work well.

Helps appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, problem is getAll is async. You can use

```
  // in controller
  // routes/index.js
  const category = require('../controllers/controller');

  router.get('/ko/faq', function(req, res, next) {
      // res.render('ko/faq', { 
      //     data: category.getAll() // 
      // });
      // all response handling done in getAll()
      category.getAll(req, res);
  });






 // controller.js
    exports.getAll = (req, res) => {
    Category.findAll()
    .then( (data) => {
      var parentArr = [];
      var childArr = [];
      for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i].parent_id === null) {
          data[i]['dataValues']["children"] = [];
           parentArr.push(data[i]['dataValues']);
          //console.log(parentArr)
        } else {
           childArr.push(data[i]['dataValues']);
           // console.log(childArr)
        }}
      for(let i = 0; i < parentArr.length; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < childArr.length; j++) {
          if(parentArr[i].id === childArr[j].parent_id) {
           parentArr[i].children.push(childArr[j]);  
          }
        }    
      }
        console.log(parentArr)
        res.render('ko/faq', { data: parentArr });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send("Error -> " + err)
      })
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I met another problem haha. Why the code, res.render( ..~~~
...}); is deleted? Because there is another key-value, i didn't mentions it though.

Comment: You mean the commented out res.render?